# Primality of numbers with decimal representation of the form XYZZZZZZZ....

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I have been investigating the following.
Take any 2-digits number (e.g. 45 ), and consider the sequence

451, 4511, 45111, 451111, 4511111...

**For how many last-digit repetitions will the sequence remain composite ? (or in other words, after how many repetitions will the sequence contain a prime number ?)**

It turns out, you need to add 772 1s to break the composite sequence.
451111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 111111 is prime

Sequences 671111..., 871111... and 121111... are the other ones exceeding 100 digits lenght (respectively with 210, 149 and 136 ones in the first prime).
Sequence 371111...** remains **always composite** due to a periodic factors repetition.

The sequences **381111... and 561111... remain composite at least until 3000 digits are added.**
Just curious to know how long this composite sequence is, and if there is anything special about these 2 numbers (38 & 56) or is the result simply statistically justified, considering that factorization is trivial only for respectively 2/3 and 5/6 of the sequences.

Same question could be applied swapping 1s with 3s,7s or 9s, but in this case, the longest sequence is 9577777..., which remains composite until 2904 7s are added (using Dario Alpern https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM to verify that).

All other non-trivial combinations remain composite only under 200 repetitions.

So, the only open question (for me ) remains: how long are the composite sequences with 1s (38111... and 56111...) ?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title in order to fit in a better way to your question (and also to attract more readers in the future).

Comment: that's perfect thanks !

Comment: You could be looking a long way: there are no repunit primes with between  $1032$  ones and $49080$ ones.  The overall pattern of repunit primes is thought likely to be broadly consistent with the density that might be suggested by the prime number theorem. I doubt there is anything special about $38$ and $56$ in particular

Comment: Hi Henry, fully agree. having "escaped" the relative dense barrage of primes under the 3000 digits, I've estimated that the two sequences have a roughly 1/4 chance to get to a length of 100000 digit.

Comment: Lokk [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000000301454592) for the case $5611111\cdots$

Comment: Thanks Peter. So we get a prime after 18720 ones, have you checked all the smaller numbers as well ?

Comment: factordb approves that the above prime is in fact the smallest of this form. $381111\cdots$ is however never prime ! , If $n$ is the number of ones , then in the case $n\equiv 1\mod 3$ , $3$ is a nontrivial divisor , in the case $n\equiv 2\mod 3$ , $37$ is a nontrivial divsor and if $n=3k$ for some positive integer $k$,  then $\frac{7\cdot 10^k-1}{3}$ is a nontrivial divisor.

Comment: nice! so question is now fully solved. In summary, sequences in the form XY1111..... have only 2 instances that are never prime, XY=37 and 38.  For XY=56 we get the longest streak of composite with first prime arising only after 18470 ones (!!!), while second largest is XY=45 (with 772 ones). Thanks Peter for helping out.